# Android Image Rotated and Resized

Tags: android, mobile, camera, preview

I looked everywhere for a solution but couldn't use anything useful. I'm using SurfaceView and FrameLayout for custom in-app camera. I have a button that calls "mCamera.takePicture()" function. In the Callback, I save the picture as it is; the problem is that the picture is rotated and flipped, and scaled in weird ratio.

I know that it is happening mostly because I set the camera parameter's setPreviewSize to an optimal size, and rotated it using mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(). The preview looks beautiful. But when I take a picture and save it, that's where it gets messed up.

```
Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
Size theSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(opt, w, h);
cp.setPreviewSize(theSize.width, theSize.height);
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mCamera.setParameters(cp);
```

The above code is written in surfaceChanged function.

How do I make the saved picture as it's shown in the preview?

Screenshot of what is shown in the preview of the camera. Size fine, rotation fine:

[image: Screenshot of what is shown in the preview of the camera. Size fine, rotation fine.]

This is after the picture has been taken. Look at the monitor, collection of CDs and the plug. It's squashed and the monitor looks like a wave:
[image: This is after the picture has been taken. Look at the monitor, collection of CDs and the plug. It's squashed and the monitor looks like a wave.]

Comment: Hey could you tell me what have you tried and whether you have solved the problem or not? Please if you could reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image returned in pictureTaken() is not effected by Camera.setDisplayOrientation(). It is in Jpeg compressed format, so you can set JPEG rotation via Exif header without decoding it. This is what [`Camera.setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) often does, but on some devices it actually performs rotation in hardware. This is the most efficient method, but some viewers may still show a rotated image.

Alternatively, you can use [JPEG lossless rotation](http://www.betterjpeg.com/lossless-rotation.htm), using [jpegtran](http://www.ijg.org).

On SourceForge, there is a Java open source class [LLJTran](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/javadocs/mediautil/image/jpeg/LLJTran.html). The Android port is [on GitHub](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil).

Comment: I already tried Exif, and it rotates the image perfectly, but the image is still flipped. I'll have a look at your links. My first priority in this is getting the crooked size of the image fixed.

Comment: What is wrong with the image size? What do you mean by _the image is still flipped_? Maybe, you can post the illustrations?

Comment: [First Picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11701729/Screenshot_2014-02-10-15-01-45.png)
  <-  That is the screenshot of what is shown in the preview of the camera. Size fine, rotation fine.

[Second Picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11701729/image_224174.jpg)

  <-   This is after the picture has been taken. Look at the monitor, collection of CDs and the plug. It's squashed and the monitor looks like a wave.

Comment: Is 640x480 the picture size you really want? I bet your [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()) list contains much better resolutions. I believe that 849x540 is a scaled image of some supported preview size. It's your choice to use a _not 4:3 aspect ratio_, but it is quite possible that your device cannot _capture pictures_ of this aspect ratio. In such case, if you want the Jpeg file to reflect the 14:9 aspect ratio, you should crop the image that is captured.

Comment: OK, here is what the Internet [says](http://androidfragmentation.com/database/v/dr/655737/oem/samsung/dm/GT-I9192/carrier/MegaFon%20RUS) about your [Galaxy 4 mini](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9190_galaxy_s4_mini-5375.php) camera: `preview-size-values=1920x1080,1280x720,960x720,800x480,720x480,640x480,320x240,176x144,144x176` `picture-size-values=3264x2448,3264x1836,2048x1536,2048x1152,1280x720,640x480`. You can choose picture size `3264x1836` with aspect ratio `16:9`.

Comment: Ah! The ratio was the problem. The back camera is fixed now. Thank you very much! But, the front camera's preview shows a stretched out image. (Just height)

Comment: Front camera: `picture-size-values=1920x1080,1392x1392,1280x720,960x720`. `preview-size-values=1392x1392,1280x720,960x720,960x540,720x720,720x480,640x480,320x240,176x144,144x176`. Can't you use **1280x720**?

Comment: Surprisingly, turns out not applying any ratio to the front camera doesn't cause any problem. But the final problem remains, which is front camera image, when saved, gets horizontally flipped. I tried ExifInterface with 'Horizontal Orientation Flip'. But the whole image gets flipped and rotated in an unexpected manner.

Comment: Sure, front camera preview is mirrored, while captured image is not. It is possible to set Exif orientation to compensate that; after all, through trial and error you can choose the correct one of 8 possible values. BTW, did you choose the Exit flag for https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11701729/image_224174.jpg, or it was set correctly by the camera?

Comment: Hello, Can anyone help with some code hints? I have followed the library mentioned above but I cant find some classes that are related with java.awt. Anyone has has the solution here ?

Comment: @Ultimo_m you should check the Android port of LLJTran on Github at http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil. But don't expect fantastic results: this library may be too slow for you. Note that [`Camera.setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) does effect the captured image, but depending on device it often only sets the EXIF orientation flag.

Comment: I have followed that library but while importing there are some classes that  are inside java classes not for android inside this package `java.awt`. Do you know any example for that of camera because what I have tried didnt give me any results. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Ultimo_m that's strange… could you please share an example?

Comment: @AlexCohn I have followed this example here https://github.com/Skykai521/StickerCamera/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/stickercamera/app/camera/ui/CameraActivity.java in line 680 you can see what is done there, the problem is that if i remove the if condition and do setRotation it rotates the camera preview and not the saved file.  In line 723 and 756 this man here has done the trick to rotate the image but for me it takes a lot of time. What do you think of this solution? Thanks

Comment: @Ultimo_m indeed, doing rotation through Java bitmap may be terribly slow, and also can easily drive your Android device out of memory. If for any reason `setRotation()` and/or EXIF orientation flag are not good for you, I recommend using NDK to perform efficient rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you know any open source code how to achieve a capture from camera with right rotation what ever the solution, just the result, you are welcomed. Thanks once again :)